# Drupal 6 on php 5.5 compatibility

Tags: 6

I have running 20+ Drupal 6 sites on php 5.4 without large issues, but what about php 5.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am doing it.  The only problem I found was with Panels, but [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1469736) fixed it.  Also, I had to turn down the default error reporting, but I've not had the site crash.

Comment: Thanks, i have turned off error reporting since php 5.4 either :)

Comment: Are you using Views with no issues? That's a huge known compatibility problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered an issue with PHP 5.5.14 and Drupal 6. The problem was that logging in was not working. It would refresh the screen and nothing happen.

The issue is that PHP 5.5.14 has very long session id's in the eyes of Drupal 6. Longer than the 64 characters allowed in the sessions table. I had to increase the size of the sid field in the session table to 255 characters in order to get login working. Once I did this, it fixed the problem. There is a similar issue for accesslog but I have not corrected that yet as it is optional and does not seem to affect functionality of my site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on PHP 5.5.

I ran in several problems, not all specific to PHP, but the main problem with PHP was the large number of notices that appeared. I have a version, on my end, that fixes most of these. I get a few when I do some obscure administration once in a while.

However, the hardest was to lose XCache. That's not directly linked to PHP, it's more to do with the fact that they upgraded to a much newer version of XCache and it caused tremendous problems with views (on all pages, not specifically on a page with a view, it's in link with loading the PHP files because the views programmers have what XCache considers bugs in there...)

I've done it a while back and I don't recall, but I think I turned off a couple of modules that would generate many errors and I was not really fond of so I could lose them.